# Condição "If" não entra na estrutura

Tags: python, if, pandas, condição

Estou tendo um problema com meu código,eu recebo um arquivo xlsx, e faço o procedimento todo correto. mas o arquivo vem com algumas virgulas que precisam ser retiradas, e quando eu faço o if pra verificar se possui a virgula ele não reconhece e não executa minha estrutura condicional, e caso não exista virgula eu não quero que faça nada, alguém pode me ajudar onde estou errando.

```
def main(bi):
    // Essa tabela possui virgula, mas ele não entra nessa condição abaixo
    if bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo, Cruise]'] == ',':
        bi['A'] = bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo,Cruise]'].str.split(',').str[0]
        bi['A'].fillna("null", inplace=True)

        def f(bi):
            if bi['A'] == "null":
                val =  bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo, Cruise]']
            else:
                    val = bi['A']
            return val
        bi['B'] = bi.apply(f, axis=1)
        bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo, Cruise]'] = bi['B']

        del bi['A']
        del bi['B']
    else:
        bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo, Cruise]']
```

Comment: Poderia exemplificar uma parte desse arquivo xlsx ?

Comment: é um arquivo xml comum, que eu transformo em uma string e depois em um DF. 
Essa coluna vem alguns numero(Ex: 123456,123456,123456) quando eu seleciono o split sem o if ele roda normalmente e a coluna passa a ficar assim (Ex : '123456'), mas quando eu faço o if verificando se possui virgula na coluna, ele não entra no split mesmo contendo virgula

Comment: Você teria que verificar então se a string possui uma vírgula, e do jeito que está, vc está conferindo se a string(conteúdo da coluna) é somente uma string

Comment: Acho que você quis dizer algo desse tipo ( if "," in bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo, Cruise]']: ) mas também não funcionou

Comment: Você consegue disponibilizar uma amostra dos seus dados, e adaptar a pergunta para que ela tenha um exemplo [minimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) do problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui achar uma forma dele verificar antes se existe essa virgula no meu DF é um pouco de Gambiarra mas funcionou assim, vou publicar o código usado.

```
\\\ Crirei uma nova variavel para checar se existe "," na minha coluna com o (str.contains) ele retonar a quantidade de linhas que existem com virgulas
bi_check = bi[bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo, Cruise]'].str.contains(",") == True]

\\\ Aqui ele verifica quantas linhas com virgula possui no arquivo.
tam = len(bi_check)

\\\ se houver virgula o arquivo sera Maior que 0 então ele vai entrar no meu If e fazer o split
if tam > 0:
     bi['A'] = bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo, Cruise]'].str.split(',').str[0]
     bi['A'].fillna("null", inplace=True)
     def f(bi):
        if bi['A'] == "null":
            val =  bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo, Cruise]']
        else:
            val = bi['A']
        return val
     bi['B'] = bi.apply(f, axis=1)
     bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo, Cruise]'] = bi['B']
     del bi['A']
     del bi['B']
\\\ caso contrario ele vai me retornar a tabela normal.
else:
 bi = bi
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o valor recebido do `bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo, Cruise]']` for uma string, então ele não entrará no `if` porque você definiu para ele a condição de se a string for igual a `","`. O correto a se fazer é colocar a condição desta forma:

```
if "," in bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo, Cruise]']:
    ...
```

Da forma que você estava fazendo, você conseguiria entrar na condicional somente se a string fosse somente um `","`.

Comment: Entendi oque quis dizer, mas não funcionou ele continua sem entrar no if, como se não existisse a virgula. o meu arquivo quando estou fazendo essa condição não e String ele é um DataFrame

Comment: Putz. Dessa forma não vou poder ajudar então porque eu não trabalho com pandas, desculpa.

Answer (score 0):

Você está fazendo a verificação errada. Na 3° linha você esta dizendo:

```
if bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo, Cruise]'] == ',':
```

É outras palavras você está verificando de essa variável é igual a uma virgula.
A verificação correta é você verificar se a variavel contém uma virgula:

```
if "," in bi['Localizador [Outros, Aéreo, Cruise]']:
```

Comment: Isso foi o mesmo exemplo que o Jean comentou logo acima, obrigado mas não funcionou assim.